# Issue with Y axis locked

Tags: fallout-4

I am not able to look up or down anymore in Fallout 4 in first person, the Y axis is stuck. It works OK in the third person view though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just sat on a chair then stood up, and it was working fine again.

I guess if you sat on a couch it'd work too, but me it was a chair.

Comment: is this in game or IRL?

Comment: @GodEmperorDune I suggest you try IRL first, just in case.